# Express server not serving my bundle.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I'm trying to serve a `bundle.js` file from my React components but am unsure why the file isn't being served. I'm using Express and have a project with these files:

```
project
    /dist
        bundle.js
    /views
       /home
          index.ejs
    /routes
       index.js
    app.js
```

In my `app.js`, I tried to serve `bundle.js`:

```
DIST_DIR = path.join(__dirname, 'dist')
app.use(express.static(DIST_DIR));
```

My simple `views/home/index.ejs` looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/styles.css'/>
</head>

<body id="main-page">
    <div class="container">
    </div>
  <script src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I finally `GET` the page in my `routes/index.js` using:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('home/index.ejs');
});

module.exports = router;
```

And this is my app.js

```
var express = require("express");
    path = require("path"),
    cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser');

    index = require('./routes/index'),
    app = express();

    DIST_DIR = path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    app.use(express.static(DIST_DIR));
    app.use('/', index);
    app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views')),
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

    module.exports = app;
```

But I come back with an error: empty response whenever I try to load the page. I'm missing something and am unsure where. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Updated above because I meant to write bundle.js in the code snippets, not index.js

Comment: Do you get that error _only_ for the `bundle.js` request, or for the entire page? The errors points to an issue in `app.js`, but it's difficult to say without more info (like route/router configuration, etc).

Comment: @robertklep I only get the error for the bundle.js request. The entire page loads fine otherwise. I've added my app.js above for more context.

Comment: Do you also get an error when you request the bundle file directly? `http://localhost:3000/bundle.js` (assuming the server runs on port 3000). And if not, does the server log anything to console?

Comment: @roberklep Yes, after waiting on localhost for a while I get a "localhost didn't send any data ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE" but nothing is on the console.

Comment: That sounds like a faulty route, one that doesn't actually send back a response causing the browser to time out the request. I don't see how that can happen for the routes that you're showing, though.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you have a `index.html` that contains a div where everything gets loaded.  If you want to build everything from scratch see something like the following, http://andrewhfarmer.com/build-your-own-starter/#0-intro

Or if you want to spend less time tooling around, and more time with react, then look at using the https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app